# How To disable API route to domains in Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, api

In my example, I have several different domains that handle different clients of mine but my application still shares them all with 1 MySQL database. So you can imagine the following:

```
Client 1 - client1.laravel.app.com
Client 2 - client2.laravel.app.com
Client 3 - client3.laravel.app.com
```

All under the one shared Database / API domain:

     `admin.laravel.app.com`

I am using the Laravel AuthKey to check API requests for the matching key in my dot environment file which I add to the header. This works fine for when I am just testing with localhost and the AuthKey deny's any unauthorized request, but when I pushed to production (which is apache server) I can access my Client Domains API routes without the App Key in the Header. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and any suggestions to fix?

Thanks :)

Comment: you can check the header app key in middleware and apply the required restriction over there.

Comment: @GauravGupta I believe I am doing that currently, inside my app/Http/Middleware/AuthKey.php I check each request header for an 'APP_KEY' then compare that with my value saved in my `.env`. It seems to only work for my localhost URL, it doesn't seem like the file is applying the rule to my other URLs.

Comment: dd your header in AuthKey.php and check what you're getting in production / live url

Comment: When I dd my header('APP_KEY') in prod. it returns null and when in local the actual key value. Why is that the case?

Comment: @GauravGupta I did the following command `php artisan config:clear` and I was able to get my error JSON saying the APP_KEY was missing but the key is still Null in the header when I do add it.

Comment: how you add app ki to your header.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by running `php artisan config:clear` and by retriveing my headers with `$headers = apache_request_headers();`

Comment: Gud to know that your issue was resolved now.

Comment: @GauravGupta I add the APP_KEY to my header via node like the following:   
const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'APP_KEY': process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY
};

// Then when I make a call using node-fetch
async function get() {
     const res = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_URL}/api/test`, { headers: header });
     const data = await res.json();
     console.log(data);
}